# Relay mail to external domains through external SMTP in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, relay

I have an internal Exchange 2010 (sp2) server setup for some development projects. The domain is called dev.net.

All users inside dev.net can reach and email eachother but I'd also like to be able to mail users outside dev.net. This isn't possible since our ISP doesn't allow smtp traffic unless it is relayed through their smtp server.

External mails back into dev.net isn't an issue at the moment since the only mails going out is reports such.

I can use either my ISP's smtp server or use Googles (secured in that case). Any solid advices where to start to look would be appreciated. There are some about relaying on the interwebs but most of them are junk (hence don't send links as replies unless you know they are good).

**This means**

- Internal mails (on dev.net) must be transported through the internal exchange servers smtp
- External mails (not dev.net) must be transported through an external smtp server

Thanks

Comment: Exchange allows using a smart host for SMTP relay, and it will automatically resolve internal mail so that it doesn't go out.

Comment: Did you solve this eventually? I'm curious as to what your solution would be